# Node-sass, node-gyp errors, how to fix?

Tags: node.js, node-gyp, node-sass

After updating the brew and reinstalling node, an error occurs when setting the dependencies.
Tell me how to solve this?

The code below is not the entire error, there is only a part since there is a limit on the number of characters.

node v10.2.1

PHP 7.2.6 (cli) (built: May 25 2018 06:18:43) ( NTS )

Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07)

```
⟩ yarn install --save-dev
yarn install v0.15.1
warning frontend_pack@1.0.0: No license field
warning frontend_pack@1.0.0: Dependency "path" listed in "devDependencies" is the name of a built-in module
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
warning lodash@1.0.2: The engine "rhino" appears to be invalid.
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning Unmet peer dependency "jquery@>=1.9.0".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
[1/1] ⠐ node-sass: not ok
[-/1] ⠐ waiting...
[-/1] ⠐ waiting...
[-/1] ⠐ waiting...
error /Users/Maxim/Projects/diod-market/Company/Bundle/CompanyBundle/Resources/static/node_modules/node-sass: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: sh
Arguments: -c node scripts/build.js
Directory: /Users/Maxim/Projects/diod-market/Company/Bundle/CompanyBundle/Resources/static/node_modules/node-sass
Output:
Building: /usr/local/Cellar/node/10.2.1/bin/node /Users/Maxim/Projects/diod-market/Company/Bundle/CompanyBundle/Resources/static/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ '/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.2.1/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/Users/Maxim/Projects/diod-market/Company/Bundle/CompanyBundle/Resources/static/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
gyp info using node@10.2.1 | darwin | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/Maxim/Projects/diod-market/Company/Bundle/CompanyBundle/Resources/static/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/Maxim/Projects/diod-market/Company/Bundle/CompanyBundle/Resources/static/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/Maxim/Projects/diod-market/Company/Bundle/CompanyBundle/Resources/static/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/Maxim/Projects/diod-market/Company/Bundle/CompanyBundle/Resources/static/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/Maxim/Projects/diod-market/Company/Bundle/CompanyBundle/Resources/static/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/Maxim/Projects/diod-market/Company/Bundle/CompanyBundle/Resources/static/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:182:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/Maxim/Projects/diod-market/Company/Bundle/CompanyBundle/Resources/static/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/Maxim/Projects/diod-market/Company/Bundle/CompanyBundle/Resources/static/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/Maxim/Projects/diod-market/Company/Bundle/CompanyBundle/Resources/static/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/Maxim/Projects/diod-market/Company/Bundle/CompanyBundle/Resources/static/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/Maxim/Projects/diod-market/Company/Bundle/CompanyBundle/Resources/static/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/Maxim/Projects/diod-market/Company/Bundle/CompanyBundle/Resources/static/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:182:21)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack:
gyp verb `which` failed    'Error: not found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError (/Users/Maxim/Projects/diod-market/Company/Bundle/CompanyBundle/Resources/static/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)\n    at F (/Users/Maxim/Projects/diod-market/Company/Bundle/CompanyBundle/Resources/static/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)\n    at E (/Users/Maxim/Projects/diod-market/Company/Bundle/CompanyBundle/Resources/static/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)\n    at /Users/Maxim/Projects/diod-market/Company/Bundle/CompanyBundle/Resources/static/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16\n    at /Users/Maxim/Projects/diod-market/Company/Bundle/CompanyBundle/Resources/static/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5\n    at /Users/Maxim/Projects/diod-market/Company/Bundle/CompanyBundle/Resources/static/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:182:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python /usr/bin/python
gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version());"` returned: "2.7.10\n"
gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 10.2.1
gyp verb command install [ '10.2.1' ]
gyp verb install input version string "10.2.1"
gyp verb install installing version: 10.2.1
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version not already installed, continuing with install 10.2.1
gyp verb ensuring nodedir is created /Users/Maxim/.node-gyp/10.2.1
gyp verb created nodedir /Users/Maxim/.node-gyp/10.2.1
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.2.1/node-v10.2.1-headers.tar.gz
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.2.1/node-v10.2.1-headers.tar.gz
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/android-ifaddrs.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/common.gypi
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/config.gypi
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/node.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/node_api.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/node_api_types.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/node_buffer.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/node_object_wrap.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/node_version.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/pthread-barrier.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/stdint-msvc2008.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/tree.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/uv-aix.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/uv-bsd.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/uv-darwin.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/uv-errno.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/uv-linux.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/uv-os390.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/uv-posix.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/uv-sunos.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/uv-threadpool.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/uv-unix.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/uv-version.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/uv-win.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/uv.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/v8-inspector-protocol.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/v8-inspector.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/v8-platform.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/v8-profiler.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/v8-testing.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/v8-util.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/v8-value-serializer-version.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/v8-version-string.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/v8-version.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/v8.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/v8config.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/zconf.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/zlib.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/aes.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/asn1.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/asn1_mac.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/asn1t.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/async.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/bio.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/blowfish.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/bn.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/bn_conf.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/bn_conf_asm.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/bn_conf_no-asm.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/buffer.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/camellia.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/cast.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/cmac.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/cms.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/comp.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/conf.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/conf_api.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/crypto.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/ct.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/des.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/dh.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/dsa.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/dso_conf.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/dso_conf_asm.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/dso_conf_no-asm.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/dtls1.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/e_os2.h
gyp verb extracted file from tarball include/node/openssl/ebcdic.h
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your `node` version [supports](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) your `node-sass` version.

Look at your `package.json` and see if
`"node-sass": "^X.X.X",` matches your node version according to the linked table.

Also,  make sure you're running the node version you want to run. Check with `which node` and if you're using `nvm` or `n`, dont forget to

```sh
nvm use X
```

or

```sh
n X
```

where X is the required node version.

Answer (score 1):

Supported Node.js versions vary by release, checkout [Node version support policy](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/blob/master/README.md#node-version-support-policy)

| NodeJS | Supported node-sass version | Node Module |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Node 19 | 8.0+ | 111 |
| Node 18 | 8.0+ | 108 |
| Node 17 | 7.0+, <8.0 | 102 |
| Node 16 | 6.0+ | 93 |
| Node 15 | 5.0+, <7.0 | 88 |
| Node 14 | 4.14+ | 83 |
| Node 13 | 4.13+, <5.0 | 79 |
| Node 12 | 4.12+, <8.0 | 72 |
| Node 11 | 4.10+, <5.0 | 67 |
| Node 10 | 4.9+, <6.0 | 64 |
| Node 8 | 4.5.3+, <5.0 | 57 |
| Node <8 | <5.0 | <57 |

In case upgrading the node-sass package is not feasible, it would be best to use a node version manager to switch to a compatible version of Nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

The key lines in the log stream might be:

```
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
```

I'd suggest installing python2 (or setting an environment variable to point to it).

N.b. [node-sass is depreciated](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-sass)